# Traer información de 2 tablas y ponerla en la misma columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta tabla de **`productos`**

```
-----------------------------
|   product   |   Nombre    |    
-----------------------------
|     58    |   RANCH       | 
-----------------------------
|     60    |   GUACAMOLE   | 
-----------------------------
|     52    |   CEBOLLA     | 
-----------------------------
```

y esta tabla de **`productoBodega`**

```
----------------------------------------------------
|   product   |   NombreB     |   CantidadB        |
----------------------------------------------------
|     58    |   RANCH       |   10                 |
----------------------------------------------------
|     61    |   GUACAMOLE   |   8                  |
----------------------------------------------------
|     53    |   TOMATE     |   1                   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que me de un resultado como el siguiente.

```
-----------------------------
|   product   |   NombreB   |
-----------------------------
|     58    |   RANCH       |  
-----------------------------
|     61    |   GUACAMOLE   | 
-----------------------------
|     52    |   CEBOLLA     |  
-----------------------------
|     53    |   TOMATE      |  
-----------------------------
```

Pero sin hacerlo con un `Union` ya que luego debo de hacer otra consulta como mostrar la `cantidad` y si no tiene cantidad poner `0`, solo que no se como unirlo sin utilizar el `Union`

Tenia esto

```
SELECT
Nombre
NombreB
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN productoBodega ON product = product
```

pero no se como unir `Nombre` con `NombreB`

Comment: probaste alguna consulta? podrias ponerla, para adaptarla a lo que necesitas

Comment: supongo que el 60 de la tabla productos debería salir pero se te ha olvidado no? (es que sinó no le encuentro la lógica).

Comment: Si, tambien debe de salir.

Comment: Por qué la restricción arbitraria de no poder usar `UNION`?, es lejos la opción más simple

Comment: Por que luego debo de agregarle la cantidad y eso hace que me dañe el `UNION`.

Comment: Este es un problema que nace de que no has explicado tu necesidad real, sería mucho mejor que expliques lo que quieres obtener al final, en vez de agregar estas restricciones que pueden o no ser necesarias

Comment: @Eduard edite mi respuesta adaptada a tus necesidades

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lo que necesitas es hacer un full outer join

```
SELECT COALESCE (p.product,pb.product) as id, COALESCE (p.Nombre,pb.NombreB) as nombre, ISNULL(pb.CantidadB,0) as cantidad
FROM productos p
FULL OUTER JOIN productoBodega pb
ON p.product = pb.product
```

saludos

Comment: El problema con esta consulta es que va a dejar `NULL` en las columnas de `Productos` cuando el dato solo está en `ProductoBodega`, no devuelve los datos como pide la pregunta...

Comment: @MarcosCrispino exacto, ahi edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Bien, ahora sí :)

Comment: Y si deseo agregarle la cantidad solo a los que tienen cantidad?

Comment: @Eduard le agregas el campo p.cantidad y deberia funcionar, claramente va a devolver NULL en caso de que no tenga. Podrias usar la funcion isnull para devolver 0 en caso de que sea null. edito mi respuesta

Comment: A mi no me da, solo me trae los de la tabla `p.Nombre`, no me aparece ni el tomate ni el aguacate

Comment: @Eduard eestas usando la consulta de mi respuesta?

Comment: Si, esa misma estoy utilizando

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que el resultado parezca una sola tabla, entonces lo mejor es hacer un `UNION`. No me queda claro por qué no te sirve esa solución.

Lo que yo haría es esto:

```
SELECT Product, Nombre
FROM Productos
UNION
SELECT Product, NombreB
FROM ProductoBodega
WHERE not exists (SELECT *
                  FROM Productos
                  WHERE Productos.Product = ProductoBodega.Product)
```

Comment: El `union` ni siquiera necesita el `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Lamak Creo que sí se necesita, porque si no los productos que están en las dos tablas van a aparecer dos veces...

Comment: no, porque estás usando `UNION`, no `UNION ALL`. `UNION` tiene un `DISTINCT` implícito

Comment: @Lamak Lo que dices es correcto si coinciden todos los valores (producto y nombre), pero no si hay algún registro en ProductoBodega con nombre distinto al que tiene en Productos...
Pero está bien la aclaración, puede ser sin el `not exists`, depende lo que realmente quiera.

Comment: El no exists sobra.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el `UNION` aunque luego tengas que realizar otra consulta para la cantidad o lo que necesites:

```
(SELECT PRODUCT, NOMBRE FROM PRODUCTOS
UNION
 SELECT PRODUCT, NOMBREB AS NOMBRE FROM PRODUCTOSBODEGA) AS TABLE_PROD
```

Ahora puedes usar este bloque en otras consultas como una única tabla llamada **TABLE_PROD** con 2 campos **PRODUCT** y **NOMBRE**.

Por ejemplo si necesitas obtener la cantidad ahora puedes usar el bloque con una `JOIN` como harías normalmente (en lugar de **TABLE_PROD** he usado **TU** para abreviar:

```
SELECT TU.PRODUCT, TU.NOMBRE, COALESCE(PB.CANTIDADB,0)  FROM 
  (SELECT PRODUCT, NOMBRE FROM PRODUCTOS
    UNION
  SELECT PRODUCT, NOMBREB AS NOMBRE FROM PRODUCTOBODEGA) TU 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTOBODEGA PB ON TU.PRODUCT=PB.PRODUCT
```

Aquí puedes ver como todo el bloeque `UNION` se trata como una tabla llamada **TU** con 2 campos.